# Clean TPL BroadcastBlock's last piece of data

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

From the TPL documentation,

> However, BroadcastBlock always maintains the last piece of data it
>   received for anyone that might be interested in consuming it; if
>   target blocks are subsequently linked from a broadcast block, the
>   target will be pushed that last piece of saved data.

I am looking for ways to clean out that lingering "last piece of data" without sending a null value, which in turn, would inadvertently feed it to its listeners.

Is there a way to do this? Note, this **BroadcastBlock** is part of a pipeline/mesh flow.

Comment: Why? That's the whole point of a `BroadcastBlock`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "flow" in which BroadcastBlock belongs to, is a reusable one. I need to clean it out first, before invoking it again. My current workaround, is to new up the entire flow again - a process which includes linking the individual blocks all over again.

Comment: BB retains the last value. You can just push another value into it.

Comment: Why not push a value indicating finalization?

Comment: What does *is a reusable one* mean? That you want to use the very same block *instance* in different meshes? Why do that instead of creating one block for each mesh? Or do you want to add subscribers dynamically that won't read the last value?

Comment: The whole "flow/mesh" in which the BroadcastBlock is a part of. I periodically "push" data to the head of this flow/mesh.

Comment: Why clean it then? When you send the next batch of data, the block will buffer and propagate the *new* events to its subscribers, not the last value. You'd have an issue only if you added new subscribers to it after a bach had ended

Comment: If you have to achieve this particular behaviour maybe create a decorator for the BroadcastBlock that simply wraps the underlying BroadcastBlock and swaps it out for a new one as and when required? Then link the wrapper block into your dataflow.

Comment: I'm looking for this functionality too. https://i.imgur.com/Dlmqmoc.png